# Page number shifted to the left

Tags: horizontal-alignment, page-numbering

I am writing a report with different geometry settings for the title page, so after finishing the latter with `\end{titlepage}`, I specified the new settings for the rest of the document using `\restoregeometry` and then `\newgeometry{letterpaper,textwidth=7in,textheight=9.5in}`.

Nevertheless, I am experiencing an issue with the page numbers: they are slightly shifted to the left. I can clearly see this by writing a centered number just over the page number (see the image below). How can I fix that?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage[letterpaper,textwidth=6.5in,textheight=9in]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[c]{--~\thepage~--}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
Title page here
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\restoregeometry
\newgeometry{letterpaper,textwidth=7in,textheight=9.5in}

\section*{Introduction}
\vfill
\begin{center}
1
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the main geometry first and then use `\newgeometry` for the title page; `fancyhdr` sets the dimensions of headers and footers according to the current geometry values.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper,textwidth=7in,textheight=9.5in}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[c]{--~\thepage~--}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{textwidth=6.5in,textheight=9in}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
Title page here
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\restoregeometry

\section*{Introduction}
\vfill
\begin{center}
1
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]